# Is it possible to clear Github's search bar suggetions of repositories that I have been in?

Tags: github

So I noticed that some repositories that I have been in appear on the search bar as a suggestion as soon as i focus on in and I wonder how I could clear this, or even if it is possible to do so.

[image: Example of What Happens on Search Bar Focus]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly: it is based on your history with the site.

If you are *not* logged in, or in a private session (again without login to the GitHub site), *then* searching would yield no suggestion when typing in the search box.

Maybe [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) can clear that history for you.
Said support actually responded (said the [OP zinks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4877981/zinks) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013841/is-it-possible-to-clear-githubs-search-bar-suggetions-of-repositories-that-i-ha/55016450#comment97085451_55016450))

> They would take the idea of clearing Github's search bar and review it.
>   And maybe without any promises implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try Github Support to see if I have any luck!

Comment: The Github Team responded back saying that they would take the idea of clearing Github's search bar and review it and maybe without any promises implement it.

Comment: @zinks Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.